# Can I use TFS 2010 proxy when there is no connectivity between the TFS server and proxy networks?

Tags: tfs

I am setting up TFS 2010 proxy server in my local network. 
The environment of main TFS sever & proxy server is like below:

The main TFS 2010 server existing the client network. The TFS 2010 server & proxy server will in different domains and networks. There is no connectivity between the server & proxy network.

OS: win 2008 64bit

**Is there any help/document/instruction to set up the proxy of TFS 2010?**

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that what you're asking is possible. The TFS proxy server automatically caches items in source control to speed up access. It won't be able to do that if it cannot connect to the TFS Server.

Answer (score 0):

This guide might help you 
[Team Foundation Installation Guide for Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=24337)